# Hive regular expressions for IP addresses

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

How do I modify the following code:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('156.154.161.94', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.$', 0) AS ip;
161.94
```

To return the first 2 or 3 octets of the IP address? In other words: `156.154` or `156.154.161`?

Comment: you could try "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"

Comment: Nothing is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two

```
SELECT regexp_extract('156.154.161.94', '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', 0) AS ip;
```

First three

```
SELECT regexp_extract('156.154.161.94', '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', 0) AS ip;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter regexp:

```
SELECT regexp_extract('156.154.161.94', '\\d+\\.\\d+', 0) AS ip; --first 2 quibbles.
```

Note that correct regexp special characters escaping in Hive is two slashes: `\\.` not one `\.`, not `\d`.